# __doPostBack JS functions do not work when the following code is in the VB file

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, gridview, visual-web-developer

I have a page that I created to let moderators of my site edit and add records of a table in a database. Since ASP.NET gridview does not allow for the INSERT (it only allows for select, edit, and delete) I added a bit in the VB file to allow for an INSERT INTO statement (and that works because it is submitted using and `asp:Button`, which is translated into html as an `<input>` as opposed to a `__doPostBack`).

The problem is that when I added the code I wasn't able to use paging or sorting on the gridview in addition to not being able to use the loginStatus (logout link) at all (even though the loginStatus is completely independent of the accessDataSource or gridview.

The actual file:

```
    <asp:LoginStatus ID="LoginStatus1" runat="server" 
            LogoutAction="RedirectToLoginPage" />
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
            AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" 
            DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="ADS" ForeColor="#333333" 
            GridLines="Horizontal" Width="100%" AutoGenerateDeleteButton="True" 
            AutoGenerateEditButton="True" AutoGenerateSelectButton="True">
           ...(irrelevant code omitted)
    <table>
        <tr><td class="style4"><asp:Label ID="lblID" runat="server" Text="ID"></asp:Label></td>
        <td class="style5"><asp:TextBox ID="tbID" runat="server" Width="127px"></asp:TextBox></td>
        <td class="style5">
            &nbsp;</td></tr>
        <tr><td class="style2"><asp:Label ID="lblHead" runat="server" Text="Head"></asp:Label></td>
        <td><asp:TextBox ID="tbHead" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
        <td>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" 
                ErrorMessage="Please enter a header" ControlToValidate="tbHead"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </td></tr>
        <tr><td class="style3"><asp:Label ID="lblBody" runat="server" Text="Body"></asp:Label></td>
        <td class="style1"><asp:TextBox ID="tbBody" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
        <td class="style1"></td></tr>
        <tr><td class="style2"><asp:Label ID="lblBy" runat="server" Text="by"></asp:Label></td>
        <td><asp:TextBox ID="tbBy" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
        <td></td></tr>
        <tr><td class="style2"><asp:Label ID="lblURL" runat="server" Text="URL"></asp:Label></td>
        <td><asp:TextBox ID="tbURL" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
        <td>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" 
                ErrorMessage="Please enter a valid url" ControlToValidate="tbURL"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator2" runat="server" 
                ErrorMessage="Please enter a valid url" ControlToValidate="tbURL" 
                Display="Dynamic" 
                ValidationExpression="http(s)?://([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+(/[\w- ./?%&amp;=]*)?"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
            </td></tr>
        <tr><td class="style2"><asp:Label ID="lblDateposted" runat="server" Text="dateposted"></asp:Label></td>
        <td><asp:TextBox ID="tbDateposted" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
        <td>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" runat="server" 
                ErrorMessage="Please enter a valid date following the current format (mm/dd/yyyy) ignore the time." 
                ControlToValidate="tbDateposted"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" 

                ErrorMessage="Please enter a valid date following the current format (mm/dd/yyyy) ignore the time." 
                ControlToValidate="tbDateposted" Display="Dynamic" 
                ValidationExpression="^(?=\d)(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:0?[13578]|1[02])(\/|-|\.)31)\1|(?:(?:0?[1,3-9]|1[0-2])(\/|-|\.)(?:29|30)\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})|(?:0?2(\/|-|\.)29\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))|(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2}))($|\ (?=\d)))?(((0?[1-9]|1[012])(:[0-5]\d){0,2}(\ [AP]M))|([01]\d|2[0-3])(:[0-5]\d){1,2})?$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
            </td></tr>
        <tr><td class="style2">
            <asp:Button ID="submit" runat="server" Text="Update" /></td>
    </tr></table>
```

And here is the VB file:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Partial Class staffcp_Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page


    Protected Sub submit_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles submit.Click
        Dim connStr As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + Server.MapPath("../App_Data/Signees.mdb")
        Dim dbConnection As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(connStr)
        Dim SQL As New OleDbCommand
        dbConnection.Open()
        SQL.Connection = dbConnection
        SQL.CommandText = "INSERT INTO aae VALUES (" + tbID.Text + ", '" + tbHead.Text + "', '" + tbBody.Text + "', '" + tbBy.Text + "', '" + tbURL.Text + "', '" + tbDateposted.Text + "')"
        SQL.ExecuteNonQuery()
        dbConnection.Close()
        SQL.Connection.Close()
    End Sub  

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim SQLResult As Object
        Dim connStr As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + Server.MapPath("../App_Data/Signees.mdb")
        Dim dbConnection As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(connStr)
        Dim SQL As New OleDbCommand
        dbConnection.Open()
        SQL.Connection = dbConnection
        SQL.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT (*) FROM aae"
        SQLResult = SQL.ExecuteScalar
        Dim count As Object = SQLResult
        dbConnection.Close()
        SQL.Connection.Close()
        tbID.Text = count.ToString + 1
        tbID.ReadOnly = True
    End Sub
End Class
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

[EDIT]: I just tried the same thing with the VB file cleared: same problem, no sorting or paging (or logging out on the loginStatus). I am seriously confused at this point.

[EDIT]: I was able to pinpoint the issue to the Update Button all the way on the bottom of the page. Can't figure out why though.

Comment: Could you reduce your code into a minimal amount of code that still exhibits the problem? We do not have your database, and can not execute the code as-is.

Answer (score 1):

Add :
    If not page.isPostBack to your code in the page_load event

Comment: Still doesn't work, however, when I switch the 'asp:Button' to a 'asp:LinkButton' the sorting and paging on the gridview and the loginStatus work fine. I can work with the LinkButton but prefer the regular Button. In addition I am simply puzzled as to why it does not work when I don't see any relationship between the two.